# Selecting max date with type on multiple records

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE PAYMENTS
(
   CTRL_NO       NUMBER                          NOT NULL,
   CUSTOMER_NO   NUMBER                          NOT NULL,
   CTYPE         VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)               NOT NULL,
   AMOUNT        NUMBER,
   PAYMENT_DATE  DATE
  )

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TEST1_PK ON PAYMENTS
(CTRL_NO)

ALTER TABLE PAYMENTS ADD (
  CONSTRAINT TEST1_PK
 PRIMARY KEY
 (CTRL_NO)
    USING INDEX 

Insert into PAYMENTS
   (CTRL_NO, CUSTOMER_NO, CTYPE, AMOUNT, PAYMENT_DATE)
 Values
   (266, 272, 'CASH', -47, TO_DATE('12/09/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into PAYMENTS
   (CTRL_NO, CUSTOMER_NO, CTYPE, AMOUNT, PAYMENT_DATE)
 Values
   (286, 272, 'CASH', 47, TO_DATE('12/12/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into PAYMENTS
   (CTRL_NO, CUSTOMER_NO, CTYPE, AMOUNT, PAYMENT_DATE)
 Values
   (701, 272, 'CASH', -200, TO_DATE('12/13/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into PAYMENTS
   (CTRL_NO, CUSTOMER_NO, CTYPE, AMOUNT, PAYMENT_DATE)
 Values
   (752, 272, 'INV', -91, TO_DATE('01/11/2012 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into .PAYMENTS
   (CTRL_NO, CUSTOMER_NO, CTYPE, AMOUNT, PAYMENT_DATE)
 Values
   (307, 252, 'AUTO', -9.35, TO_DATE('12/12/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into .PAYMENTS
   (CTRL_NO, CUSTOMER_NO, CTYPE, AMOUNT, PAYMENT_DATE)
 Values
   (126, 252, 'AUTO', -128, TO_DATE('12/05/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into .PAYMENTS
   (CTRL_NO, CUSTOMER_NO, CTYPE, AMOUNT, PAYMENT_DATE)
 Values
   (86, 252, 'INV', -18, TO_DATE('12/05/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into .PAYMENTS
   (CTRL_NO, CUSTOMER_NO, CTYPE, AMOUNT, PAYMENT_DATE)
 Values
   (5890, 400, 'CASH', 120, TO_DATE('03/07/2012 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into .PAYMENTS
   (CTRL_NO, CUSTOMER_NO, CTYPE, AMOUNT, PAYMENT_DATE)
 Values
   (5888, 400, 'CASH', 76.41, TO_DATE('03/07/2012 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into .PAYMENTS
   (CTRL_NO, CUSTOMER_NO, CTYPE, AMOUNT, PAYMENT_DATE)
 Values
   (5886, 400, 'CASH', 86.34, TO_DATE('03/07/2012 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into .PAYMENTS
   (CTRL_NO, CUSTOMER_NO, CTYPE, AMOUNT, PAYMENT_DATE)
 Values
   (5680, 400, 'CASH', 158.97, TO_DATE('03/06/2012 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into .PAYMENTS
   (CTRL_NO, CUSTOMER_NO, CTYPE, AMOUNT, PAYMENT_DATE)
 Values
   (5819, 400, 'CASH', -40.94, TO_DATE('03/06/2012 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into .PAYMENTS
   (CTRL_NO, CUSTOMER_NO, CTYPE, AMOUNT, PAYMENT_DATE)
 Values
   (718, 400, 'INV', -40.04, TO_DATE('12/21/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
COMMIT;
```

I am trying to get the sum(amount) of last cash transaction. If there isn't any, then simply return 0.

this is the query I have so far:

```
select p1.customer_no, max( p1.payment_date ) , 
( select nvl(sum(p2.amount), 0) 
  from payments p2
  where p2.ctype = 'CASH' 
  and p2.customer_no = p1.customer_no
   ) as last_payment_date 
 from payments p1
 group by p1.customer_no
  order by p1.customer_no ;
```

The problem is that 272 should be 11-jan-12 -200, but the above query returns 13-dec-11 -200. Also, I should get 400 7-mar-12 282.75 instead of 400.78.

Comment: if p2.amount can be null I think you'd want to do the nvl inside the sum so sum(nvl(p2.amount,0))  otherwise when a null is encountered the sum will result in null instead of 0.

Comment: yes, but it is not necessary for the inserts given. thanks.

Comment: Hi, please try to post only relevant code and spell things correctly it helps people answering your question to understand it more easily and SO will underline incorrectly spelled words in red to help you find them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
WITH CTE AS
(
select p1.customer_no, max(p1.payment_date) max_dt  
from payments p1
group by p1.customer_no
), CTE2 AS
(
select A.customer_no, sum(A.amount) amount 
from payments A 
WHERE ctype = 'CASH' 
AND payment_date = (SELECT max(x.payment_date) 
                    FROM payments X WHERE X.ctype = 'CASH'
                    AND A.customer_no = X.customer_no)
group by A.customer_no
)
SELECT A.customer_no, A.max_dt, nvl(amount,0) amount 
FROM CTE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE2 B 
ON A.customer_no = B.customer_no 
ORDER BY A.customer_no;
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ecb56/14)

Comment: Now, the real issue is that this is one of the calculations part of a much bigger query. I am not sure how am I going to integrate all this with the bigger query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select p1.customer_no, max( p1.payment_date ) , 0
from payments p1
where not exists ( select 1 from payments p2 where p2.customer_no = p1.customer_no and ctype = 'CASH' ) 
group by p1.customer_no

 union

select p1.customer_no, payment_date, nvl(sum(amount),0)
from payments p1 inner   join ( select customer_no, max(payment_date ) as max_date from payments where ctype = 'CASH'  group by customer_no ) subQ
on  ( p1.customer_no = subQ.customer_no
       and p1.payment_date = subQ.max_date 
) 
group by p1.payment_date, p1.customer_no
```

feels painful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your expected output but here's my version - you will see last payment date against each row with ctype = CASH. You can limit the output with WHERE in main query. You can use LAG() to fill blanks etc... 270 with CASH max date is 12/13/2011, NOT this date 1/11/2012 bcs ctype = INV in JAN. You prob. made a mistake when inserted values. Hope it helps:

```
SELECT customer_no
 , ctype
 , amount
 , payment_date
 , ( SELECT max(payment_date) 
       FROM stack_test
      WHERE ctype = 'CASH' 
        AND a.customer_no = customer_no
        AND a.ctype = ctype
   ) last_payment_date
 FROM stack_test a
 /

CUSTOMER_NO    CTYPE    AMOUNT    PAYMENT_DATE    LAST_PAYMENT_DATE
-------------------------------------------------------------------
272            CASH       -47       12/9/2011     12/13/2011
272            CASH        47       12/12/2011    12/13/2011
272            CASH      -200       12/13/2011    12/13/2011 -- This is CASH max date --
272            INV       -91        1/11/2012                -- This is INV max date not CASH --
252            AUTO      -9.35      12/12/2011    
252            AUTO      -128       12/5/2011    
252            INV       -18        12/5/2011    
400            CASH      120        3/7/2012       3/7/2012
400            CASH      76.41      3/7/2012       3/7/2012
400            CASH      86.34      3/7/2012       3/7/2012
400            CASH      158.97     3/6/2012       3/7/2012
400            CASH      -40.94     3/6/2012       3/7/2012
400             INV      -40.04     12/21/2011
```

More examples as per your comments:

```
-- Max date by trans type --
  SELECT ctype, max(payment_date) max_cash_date
   FROM stack_test
  GROUP BY ctype
 ORDER BY 2
 /

CTYPE    MAX_CASH_DATE
-----------------------
AUTO    12/12/2011
INV     1/11/2012
CASH    3/7/2012

-- Example of using analytic functions - not needed in this case --
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT customer_no, ctype
    , MAX(payment_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ctype ORDER BY ctype) max_cash_date
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ctype ORDER BY ctype) rno
    , amount
 FROM stack_test
 )
-- WHERE rno=1  -- Optional - retunrns same rows as above --
ORDER BY ctype
/
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to get the total for last cash transaction. So, there should be one record for 272, 252, and 400. For 272 > amount: -200, last_payment_Date > 12/13/2011.  For 252 > amount: 0 (since none of the ctypes is cash) last_payment_Date 12/12/2011. etc. etc.

Comment: @FALCONSEYE - it is very hard for me to help if I do not see desired output. I'm not able to crunch such things in mind, sorry. I probably misunderstood your requirements.